# "Tuple index out of range" Error?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, does anyone know? I keep getting an error that says "Tuple index out of range." I'm following a tutorial for school and I seem to be doing everything right, however I keep getting this error. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you so much.

```
animal = input("Enter any LARGE animal: ")
smallAnimal = input("Enter any SMALL animal: ")
weapon = input("Enter a sharp weapon: ")

def createDictionary():

    storyDict = dict()
    storyDict['animal'] = animal
    storyDict['smallAnimal'] = smallAnimal
    storyDict['weapon'] = weapon

return storyDict

def main():

    dictionary = createDictionary()

    animalFormat = """Once upon a time, there was a very, very large {animal}. This {animal} was the meanest, baddest, most gruesome {animal} there     was. And one day, a wild {1} had
    stepped on the {animal}'s foot. At that moment, the {1} knew it had messed up. This made the {animal} angry, so he took a {weapon} and STABBED the 
    {smallAnimal}with it! The {smallAnimal} squirmed and fought to get out, but it was no match for the {animal} with a {weapon}.

    The End."""

    withSubstitutions = animalFormat.format(**dictionary)
    print(withSubstitutions)


main()
```

Comment: Where is the error occurring?  What are you providing as input?

Comment: What is storyDict = dict()? not storyDict = {}?

Comment: Scott, The error is occurring at withSubstitutions = animalFormat.format(**dictionary). I am trying to get the story to print with the user's input of animal, smallAnimal, and weapon. If that is what you are asking.

Comment: Omid, storyDict = dict() is the way I was taught to make the dictionary. Is that correct?

Comment: @Sammy no. use dicts = {} to create a new dict. Also, instead of having multiple lines assigning the values, why not create and initialize the dict like so? `def get_dict(): return {'animal': animal, 'smallAnimal': smallAnimal, 'weapon', weapon}`. Less typing = better.

Comment: also, i made an edit to your post to show these changes.

Comment: @Sammy - `dict()` is correct syntactically, but the bracket notation `{}` is faster (not important specifically for your code) and has more flexibility for keyword types. For instance `{1:'A', 2:'B'}` works but `dict(1='A', 2='B')` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In animalFormat, replace:

```
{1}
```

With:

```
{smallAnimal}
```

This change must be made in two places.

Since you are supplying arguments to `format` with keywords, there is nothing for `1` to refer to.

#### Simpler example

Observe that this works:

```
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> 'Twice {a} is {b}'.format(**d)
'Twice 1 is 2'
```

But this does not work:

```
>>> 'Twice {1} is {b}'.format(**d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

If you are supplying `format` with keyword arguments, there is nothing for `1` to refer to.

It is possible to supply both positional arguments and keyword arguments.  For example:

```
>>> 'Twice {1} is {b}'.format('Arg0', 'ArgOne', **d)
'Twice ArgOne is 2'
```

#### Complete working code

```
animal = input("Enter any LARGE animal: ")
smallAnimal = input("Enter any SMALL animal: ")
weapon = input("Enter a sharp weapon: ")

def createDictionary():

    storyDict = dict()
    storyDict['animal'] = animal
    storyDict['smallAnimal'] = smallAnimal
    storyDict['weapon'] = weapon

    return storyDict

def main():

    dictionary = createDictionary()

    animalFormat = """Once upon a time, there was a very, very large {animal}. This {animal} was the meanest, baddest, most gruesome {animal} there     was. And one day, a wild {smallAnimal} had
    stepped on the {animal}'s foot. At that moment, the {smallAnimal} knew it had messed up. This made the {animal} angry, so he took a {weapon} and STABBED the_
    {smallAnimal}with it! The {smallAnimal} squirmed and fought to get out, but it was no match for the {animal} with a {weapon}.

    The End."""

    withSubstitutions = animalFormat.format(**dictionary)
    print(withSubstitutions)


main()
```

Sample run:

```
Enter any LARGE animal: Lion
Enter any SMALL animal: Mouse
Enter a sharp weapon: knife
Once upon a time, there was a very, very large Lion. This Lion was the meanest, baddest, most gruesome Lion there     was. And one day, a wild Mouse had
    stepped on the Lion's foot. At that moment, the Mouse knew it had messed up. This made the Lion angry, so he took a knife and STABBED the 
    Mousewith it! The Mouse squirmed and fought to get out, but it was no match for the Lion with a knife.

    The End.
```

Comment: Hello John, thank you for pointing that out. I was editing old code and forgot to remove the {1}. However, I am still getting the error.

Comment: @Sammy You have to eliminate it in both places.  After I did that, your code worked for me.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I just made a stupid mistake. Extremely helpful advice, thank you so much John!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up formatting string by keywords and ordered data.

MCVE:

```
s = "{0}{k}".format(k='something')
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Since your template contains placeholders for ordered arguments (`{1}`), you need to pass them to your function:

```
animalFormat = """Once upon a time, there was a very, very large {animal}. This {animal} was the meanest, baddest, most gruesome {animal} there     was. And one day, a wild {1} had
stepped on the {animal}'s foot. At that moment, the {1} knew it had messed up. This made the {animal} angry, so he took a {weapon} and STABBED the 
{smallAnimal}with it! The {smallAnimal} squirmed and fought to get out, but it was no match for the {animal} with a {weapon}.

The End."""

d = {'animal': 'X', 'smallAnimal': 'Y', 'weapon': 'Z'}
a = ['A', 'B']  # placeholder
animalFormat.format(*a, **d)  # works fine
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your detailed reply. I did not mean to have the {1} in my code, I was editing old code and forgot to replace that with smallAnimal. After I replace that, I still get the error. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you have **named substitution** (such as `.. very large {animal} ..`) as well as **positional substitution** (such as `At that moment, the {1} knew ..`).

Consider passing something like:

```
animalFormat.format("Replacement for {0}", "Replacement for {1}", **dictionary)
```

In the above case, positional portion of the substition will read:

```
At the moment, the Replacement for {1} knew ..
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It has been fixed.